# How should one correctly copy public and private keys from one mac to another?

Tags: ssh

I am aware of solution for linux [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine).

How should one correctly copy public and private keys from one mac to another?

Comment: For public keys, you can use ssh-copy-id, just like in the answer you linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655450/how-do-you-install-ssh-copy-id-on-a-mac

Comment: Private keys is a different question...